# ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'seniat.url' - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have this wizard class:

```
from odoo import fields, models, api


class WizardUrlSeniat(models.TransientModel):

_name = "wizard.seniat.url"

url1 = fields.Char(
    string='URL1', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url1(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' fiscal information from partner')
url2 = fields.Char(
    string='URL2', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url2(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' retention rate from partner (RIF)')
url3 = fields.Char(
    string='URL3', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
    default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),
    help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
    ' retention rate from partner (CI or Passport)')

@api.multi
def _get_url(self): 
    """ Get seniat web page
    """
    url = self.env['seniat.url']
    url_ids = url.search([]) 
    if len(url_ids) > 1:
        url.unlink.self.env.url_ids[1:] 
    url_obj = self.env['seniat.url'].browse(url_ids)
    return url_obj 
@api.multi
def _get_url1(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.name


@api.multi
def _get_url2(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.url_seniat

@api.multi
def _get_url3(self): 
    url_obj = self._get_url() 
    return url_obj.url_seniat2

@api.multi
def update_url(self): 
    for url in self:
        url_obj = self._get_url() 
        url_obj.write(
            {'name': url.url1, 
             'url_seniat': url.url2, 
             'url_seniat2': url.url3 
        })
    return {}
```

Every time I try this, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1101, in default_get
defaults[name] = field.default(self)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 41, in <lambda>
default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_url_seniat.py", line 70, in _get_url3
return url_obj.url_seniat2
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 860, in __get__
self.determine_value(record)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 960, in determine_value
record._prefetch_field(self)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 3044, in _prefetch_field
result = records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 2984, in read
self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 3112, in _read_from_database
cr.execute(query_str, params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/sql_db.py", line 141, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/sql_db.py", line 218, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 129, in getquoted
pobjs = [adapt(o) for o in self._seq]
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'seniat.url'
```

The error comes on `_get_url` method.

I think the problem is that I call `seniat_url` which is a class, then it should parse it, looking for a string, which should be `Char` field containing a name or an url.

But I'm pretty confused, because `url_ids = url.search([])` should look for it, but at the same time, I already did `url = self.env['seniat.url']`, so I don't know if the order is wrong, because `seniat.url` is the model, so, if I work on it with `url_ids` it already has `seniat.url` as class, so it's useless.

By the way, this is from a mirgation I'm doing, the original wizard looked like this:

```
class WizardUrlSeniat(osv.osv_memory):

def _get_url(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Get seniat web page
    """
    url = self.pool.get('seniat.url')
    url_ids = url.search(cr, uid, [])
    if len(url_ids) > 1:
        url.unlink(cr, uid, url_ids[1:])
    url_obj = url.browse(cr, uid, url_ids, context=None)[0]
    return url_obj

def _get_url1(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    url_obj = self._get_url(cr, uid, ids, context)
    return url_obj.name

def _get_url2(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    url_obj = self._get_url(cr, uid, ids, context)
    return url_obj.url_seniat

def _get_url3(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    url_obj = self._get_url(cr, uid, ids, context)
    return url_obj.url_seniat2

def update_url(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    data = self.pool.get('wizard.seniat.url').read(cr, uid, ids)[0]
    url_obj = self._get_url(cr, uid, ids, context)
    url_obj.write(
        {'name': data['url1'],
         'url_seniat': data['url2'],
         'url_seniat2': data['url3']})
    return {}

_name = "wizard.seniat.url"
_columns = {
    'url1': fields.char(
        string='URL1', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
        default=lambda s: s._get_url1(),
        help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
        ' fiscal information from partner'),
    'url2': fields.char(
        string='URL2', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
        default=lambda s: s._get_url2(),
        help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
        ' retention rate from partner (RIF)'),
    'url3': fields.char(
        string='URL3', size=255, required=True, readonly=False,
        default=lambda s: s._get_url3(),
        help='In this field enter the URL from Seniat for search the'
        ' retention rate from partner (CI or Passport)'),
}

WizardUrlSeniat()
```

Any ideas?

If You need more info, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one Issue in **_get_url** method.

In **odoo API search method** is returning **Browse** records and it is called **RecordSet**.

**url_ids = url.search([])**

In above search line odoo will return url **Browse** records.

```
@api.multi
def _get_url(self): 
    """ Get seniat web page
    """
    url_obj = self.env['seniat.url']
    urls = url_obj.search([]) 
    if len(urls) > 1:
        urls[1:].unlink() 
    return urls
```

When you call above method then you will get url browse record.

If you need list of ids then you need to use ids property.

Ex: urls.ids()

This may help you.

Comment: you should get rid of the term "browse record" ;-) The new concept is called "RecordSet".